# Regular passive forms of "facere"

Tags: verbs, example-request, morphology

Have regular passive forms of the verb *facere* ever been used?
If so, what is the first occurrence?

In all of the Latin I have seen, the passive forms of *facere* are replaced by *fieri*.
Regular passive forms are easy to form (*facior, faceris, facitur…*) but appear to be completely out of use, at least in classical Latin.
Regular passive forms can occur with prefixes like *satis-* or perhaps prepositions, but in this question I am only interested in the plain *facere*.

[Nigidius (Grammatica)](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/590/1/0/990-997@1#0) writes: *uti 'facit' 'ποιεῖ', ita 'facitur' 'ποιεῖται' est.*
I would not count this as proper use in a sentence.

If my corpus searches are to be trusted, there are no proper classical uses of *faci* and other such forms from the present stem.
But did such forms ever come to use?
If yes, when?
If you think such forms were never used, why do you think so?

Comment: Leumann mentions **four** occurrences only: two occurrences of **faciatur**: parui ... faciatur (Titinius, 97); faciantur [goes: faciatur] si tibi videtur, et triclinia (Petronius, Sat. 71); **satisfacitur** (Varro Men. 82), and **calfaciantur** (Vitr.)

Comment: @AlexB. Those two occurrences of plain *facere* would make a good answer.

Comment: It had long been my observation that fio *tends* to be used instead of the passive of facio; still, I admit that when I read this question, my initial reaction was, 'That can't be right! It can't possibly be so one-sided!' And yet my own search (just on PHI) seems to confirm your findings; the passive forms of facio really aren't used very much at all (and mostly in compounds) – at least for pres., fut., and impf. tenses (obviously, it's impossible to say anything definitive about pf., fut.pf., and plupf., because the 2 verbs look identical in those tenses). A very illuminating question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passive forms of *facio* are rarely written, attestations such as in the Peregrinatio Egeriae and the Latin Dioscorides suggest that this might actually have been somewhat more frequent in spoken (vulgar) language. Also that some (normative) Grammarians insisted that *facior* does not exist may indicate that it was actually used. All known examples are listed in Thesaurus Linguae Latinae, Lipsiae 1900sqq., vol. VI,2 col. 83,1ff.

Comment: Are you the famous TLL lexicographer?